Export/Backup Safari Profile
Is there a way to export or backup a Safari profile? Every time I want to switch profiles, the list is too long.
I need a lot of profiles, but need to use them only once in a while.
Exporting them as a file/folder with all the metadata, cookies, history and so on could allow me to delete most of my profiles.
platform: MacOS
safari version: Version 17.5 (19618.2.12.11.6)
